# Will the already indexed URLs be removed if I use a robots.txt for my site?

Tags: seo, google-search, robots.txt, search-engine-indexing, 404

Many URLs from my site have been added to Google's index, but a lot of them are outdated and they will never result in a `404` error and take the user to my site's homepage.

I have submitted a new sitemap with my latest URLs, but the the old and obsolete URLs of my site are still shown on top in  Google search. There're 100's of such URLs.

I know about creating URL removal requests and *robot.txt*. But submitting removal requests will take a lot of time and effort. I would like to use *robots.txt* instead. But if I list them in my *robots.txt* using a wild card expression that matches my old URLs, will Google remove them from its index? Or will it just stop crawling them again, which means they will not be re-indexed, but already indexed old URLs will still be shown in Google search, which is not I want. Can you please let me know what I should do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I block Google from crawling a page using a robots.txt disallow directive, will it disappear from search results? https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/faq

> Blocking Google from crawling a page is likely to decrease that page's
>   ranking or cause it to drop out altogether over time. It may also
>   reduce the amount of detail provided to users in the text below the
>   search result. This is because without the page's content, the search
>   engine has much less information to work with.
>
> However, robots.txt Disallow does not guarantee that a page will not
>   appear in results: Google may still decide, based on external
>   information such as incoming links, that it is relevant. If you wish
>   to explicitly block a page from being indexed, you should instead use
>   the noindex robots meta tag or X-Robots-Tag HTTP header. In this case,
>   you should not disallow the page in robots.txt, because the page must
>   be crawled in order for the tag to be seen and obeyed.

Answer (score 4):

This is the official answer from Google on this: [Completely remove an entire page](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663419?hl=en)

If you want a page removed, then you have to fill out the remove page from index form in the Google Webmaster Tools page **AND** use the *robots.txt* file to exclude the pages so Google doesn't index them again.

They state in the link above that if the page exists in Google's index and you just use the *robots.txt* file alone to exclude the page, then it **may** be indexed by Google:

> If the page still exists, use robots.txt to prevent Google from
>   crawling it. Even if a URL is disallowed by robots.txt we may still
>   index the page if we find its URL on another site. However, we won't
>   index the page if it's blocked in robots.txt and there is an active
>   URL removal request for the page.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Google Webmasters Tools option is not a good one for a lot of URLs. It also can take a long time to work- months in fact- if at all. Always think of how the web works first and forget about what Google says. Google sometimes goes off the deep-end. Instead, use the robots.txt file to remove the pages. That is in part what it is there for. I like your answer, but the missing link is Google's inability to handle large number of requests and handle any request in a timely manner.

Comment: The idea that the removal tool in webmaster tools takes 'months' is demonstrably false. Enter a url to be removed in webmaster tools. Check back the next day and it will report denied or removed. There is no 'months' to wait for that response, a day or so at the very most.

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure that the outdated pages either do a `301` redirect to your home page, or give a `404` or `410` status code.

Google will eventually remove the pages from search results, if you put the URLs in `robots.txt`. However, that might take some time.

Fastest way is to use Webmaster Tools and remove the URLs there.